# Add specific services to network location with terminal

Tags: terminal, network, automation

I want to automate the creation of my network locations (say `Home` and `Work`) and was looking into `networksetup -createlocation <location name> [populate]`

Adding `populate` adds default services to the network location (USB LAN, Wi-Fi, Bluetooth PAN, Thunderbolt Bridge) and without leaves the location empty.

Is there a way to add specific services to a network location? `networksetup -printcommands | grep -i location` is not coming up with anything helpful.

Answer (score 1):

*networksetup* uses a somehow hierarchical name system for the subcommands. *location* subcommands are used to manage locations itself only: you can either list, get (the current), create, delete or switch between locations.

Modifying the network services of a location is done in the *networkservice* "name space".

To manage the network services in **one** location you can either use  "blacklisting" or a "whitelisting":

If you execute `networksetup -createlocation <location name>` **with** `populate` and remove unwanted network services it's blacklisting, **without** `populate` you have to add all required network services and it's rather whitelisting.

To remove a network service in case of blacklisting use:

```
... -removenetworkservice <networkservice>
```

To add a network service in case of whitelisting use:

```
...  -createnetworkservice <networkservice>
```

Comment: I wanted to go for a whitelisting approach but failed to see how to do it. As pointed out in the other answer, one has to switch to the new location as `networksetup` can only create services on the current one. This feels weird to me, as this means losing connectivity. Any way to do this while keeping connectivity?

Comment: @oschrenk Transfer a shell script (starting with `networksetup -switchlocation (local)` and containing all other networksetup commands for (local) **and** finally a `networksetup -switchlocation` (remote)) to the remote stdin!

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page for networksetup ([`man networksetup`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html))

> `-createlocation location [populate]`
>    Create a set with the user-defined-name name and optionally populate it with the default
>   services.

So, the behavior you are seeing is expected.  You don't need to use the `populate` function; just add your services al la carte as needed.

That said, before you can modify a location, you have to *switch* to it first (make it active):

```
$ networksetup -listlocations             <------ Lists all locations configured
$ networksetup -getcurrentlocation        <------ Currently selected location
$ networksetup -switchlocation location  <------ Sets current location
```

Using your two locations (Home and Work), switch to the location you want then add/modify/remove the service(s) in question

For example, to create a "TestLAN" service using the Bluetooth PAN hardware device on the Home network, use the following:

```
$ networksetup -switchlocation Home
$ networksetup -createnetworkservice TestLAN "Bluetooth PAN"
```

Additional commands you may wish to explore with `networksetup` are:

```
-listallhardwareports
-listlocations
-listnetworkserviceorder
-listallnetworkservices
```

However, most importantly, you should explore the man page for more details.

Comment: Switching network location was the missing link for me. My brain got stuck on the idea to pass a service to a location. Switching to the new location and then creating the services still feels weird actually as that means losing connectivity. How is this done from remote?

Comment: Use a bash script on the remote so it will continue to execute commands when you get disconnected.  I would probably do a PoC locally first, perfect it, then upload/run the script on the remote.  You don't what to inadvertently kill access to your machine remotely by disabling a network adapter/service